# Methods that throw an exception that do not require catching

Tags: java

Sorry if this is a very basic question

As for my understanding if you have a method that throws an exception, you are required to catch it (or throw it) whenever you will be using that method.

However some methods that throw an exception do not require me to catch it like:

```
int num = Long.parseInt(sampleString);
```

Can anybody shed some light please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of exceptions in Java: **checked** and **unchecked**. The former needs to be `catch`ed while the latter does not. An unchecked `Exception` is a class that extends either `RuntimeException`, `Error`, or one of their subclasses.

[`Long#parseLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29) throws a [`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) which **IS-A** [`RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html). Thus, it's an unchecked exception and does not need to be caught.

#### References:

- [Unchecked Exceptions -- The Controversy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are exceptions which extend from `RuntimeException`.  These are known as unchecked exceptions and they do not have to be declared in your method signatures.  Generally, these are reserved for things which have *really* gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of exceptions in Java.  Checked and unchecked.  Unchecked exceptions don't need to be caught.  A good example of an unchecked exception is NullPointerException; you can see that if developers needed to catch this exception code would be ridiculously complicated.  It would be lunacy.  The exception that `parseInt` throws in an unchecked exception.

Answer (score 0):

Those are subclasses of the [`RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html). `RuntimeException`s and its subclasses don't need to be caught. They are called unchecked exceptions.